# Errors while scraping pages with json and scrapy

Tags: windows, python-3.x, scrapy

I am scraping producthunt.com using Scrapy with Python3 on Win10. I am confused by my code behaviour, which duplicates some fields in output data.
Can anyone point at the reason of that and suggest a solution?

Code:
http://pastebin.com/VvFGCmDJ

Sample of the output:
http://pastebin.com/ffx0HN54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run your code but creating the `Item` instance definitely needs to be inside the `for` loop:

```
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        topic = jsonresponse['posts']
        for post in topic:

            service = ProducthuntItem()

            service['name'] = post['name'].replace(";", " ")
            ...
```

Comment: Of course! Looks like this is the actual problem. I will test it and accept later today.
Thanks.